# Portable .so installation script on linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

Is there an accepted way to install shared object libraries on linux? I am writing a script which needs to install to `/usr/local/lib64/` on some distributions (like RHEL) and to `/usr/local/lib/` on others (like Ubuntu).

Is there a way to detect the location that `so` files should be installed to?

Some possibilities that I have considered:

- Read the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` to check for paths searched by the dynamic linker.
- Run `ldconfig -p` to see where most libraries are installed and make some programatic decision based on that
- Check the distribution and use a decoder in the script